# Asp.Net Core 2.0 Search My View In Shared

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have controller with two parameter  (page , title) the problem when redirect to view return me the following error

> InvalidOperationException: The view 'Index' was not found. The
>   following locations were searched:  /Views/Shared/Index.cshtml

if I make my controller accept one parameter, controller is working fine.

```
  [Route("~/Section/{page}/{title}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int page,string title)
    {
        SectionViewModel model = new SectionViewModel();
        var category =await _categoryService.GetCategory(CommonHelper.DashToSpace(title));
        model.news =await _newsService.GetNewsByCategory(category.Id.ToString(),pageIndex: 1);
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: Change `[Route("~/Section/{page}/{title}")]` to `[Route("Section/{page}/{title}")]`

Comment: still not working

Comment: Do you have a View called Index sitting in the same folder as this specific Controller?

Comment: yes, and i make controller accept one parameter is working fine but when i add two parameters not working also when move my view called index from section folder to shared folder working with two parameters

Comment: This has nothing to do with routes, params, or any of that other nonsense. When you return `View(model)` it's going to look for either `Views\{ControllerName}\Index.cshtml` or `Views\Shared\Index.cshtml`. The error is telling you that it could not find either. Figure out why and you're golden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message says it looked in the Shared folder for a view named Index.

Do you have a view in /Views/{Controller}/Index.cshtml?

Comment: yes,have a view in /Views/{Controller}/Index.cshtml

Comment: I'm guessing it works with the View in the correct folder.